# About /t/ glottalized before (schwa + n)

Tags: pronunciation

Why is it that /t/ is glottalized before (schwa + n) but flapped before (schwa + any other consonant)?

**Examples:**

- button -> "buh-n" but not "budden".
- kitten -> "kih-n" but not "kidden".
- flatten -> "fla-n" but not "fladden".
- straighten -> "stray-n" but not "straiden".
- eaten -> "ee-n" but not "eaden".

But meanwhile,

- "butter" -> "budder"
- "better" -> "bedder"

Comment: I think this is a more recent change. For me (AmE, Gen X), those are still flaps, but I hear a lot nowadays the glottal stop. Also, I think this is only for American English and not British or other English where they have an aspirated alveolar stop.

Comment: @Mitch Nah, I don't believe you: you’re just kitten around. Who the heck makes *kitten around* a homophone of *kiddin’ around* anyway? How does that even work?

Comment: @Mitch No, we have all three there, the least likely being an aspirated stop. By definition that could only be aspirated if there is an actual vowel after the /t/, but in this position it would only be lightly aspirated even then; it's not word initial or preceding a stressed syllable or long vowel. But it's unlikely that a speaker would have a vowel there anyway.

Comment: @Mitch: I think this pronunciation has been around in American English for decades, but the number of people using it may be increasing. A 1958 book found in Google books (*The Structure of American English* by Winthrop Francis) contains *"In some dialects the glottal stop is substituted for [t] before a syllabic lateral or nasal, as in bottle and button"*. The pronunciation seems to be dying out for *bottle*, but becoming more widespread for *button*.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Why is it that /t/ is glottalized before (schwa + n) but flapped before (schwa + any other consonant)?

It usually happens when an [alveolar stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_stop) (/t/ or /d/) is followed by the [alveolar nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_nasals) /n/ (and sometimes /m/).

In all the words you've mentioned, the /t/ and /n/ are a part of unstressed syllables. There's a very weak vowel (schwa) between the stop and the nasal. And in unstressed syllables, the vowels usually get dropped.

So when the intervening vowel is dropped, we get a stop (/t/ or /d/) immediately followed by a nasal (/n/).
This results in the final nasal taking on the full measure of the syllable (syllabic — acts as the peak of a syllable).
In this case, it's known as *[syllabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant) n*, represented in the IPA by **[n̩]**.

If the syllabic /n/ is preceded by an alveolar stop, the plosive is not often released at the alveolar ridge in the normal way, rather, it's [released nasally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_release) by lowering the velum at the back of the mouth, allowing airflow through the nose. 'Nasal release' is represented by writing a superscript nasal ([<sup>**n**</sup>]) over the plosive.

It's particularly noticeable when the stop and nasal are *homorganic* (have the same place of articulation like /t/ and /n/).

So for example 'button': the last syllable is unstressed and when the vowel between the /t/ and /n/ is dropped, the /n/ becomes syllabic and the /t/ is released nasally: [ˈbʌt<sup>n</sup>n̩].

Another example would be *sudden*: [ˈsʌ.d<sup>n</sup>n̩]

Using glottal stop instead of /t/ in an unstressed syllable is also common as in *button*: [ˈbʌ.ʔ<sup>n</sup>n̩].

Note that the glottal stop never replaces word-initial /t/ and a stressed /t/. So the /t/ in words like *top* is never replaced by a glottal stop.

We also have syllabic *l* as in *little* (here the stop is [released *laterally*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_release_(phonetics))): [lɪ.t<sup>l</sup>l̩]

and syllabic *m* as in *rhythm*: [rɪ.ðm̩].

It doesn't happen in 'butter', because there's a vowel between /t/ and /r/ and there's no nasal here.

Comment: Nice post, but isn't it the case tht the /t/ may be part of the preceding syllable and the (schwa +) in the next syllable? [Or are you saying that you can have a syllable starting with a glottal stop in English ?]

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Latter. The second syllable is weak and sometimes starts with a glottal stop followed by a syllabic n ([bʌ.ʔn̩]). My Aussie friend pronounces 'enlighten' with a glottal stop followed by a syllabic n. Of course the last syllable starts with a glottal stop: [ə̃nˈlɑɪ.ʔn̩] for her.

Comment: Though the last syllable usually starts with a t followed by syllabic n.

Comment: So do you think you can use a glottal in a syllable like *top*?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Nope. :P Glottal stop never replaces word initial /t/ or a stressed /t/.

Comment: Nor in most analyses can it be a syllable initial /t/!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: No? How? There are lots of syllable-initial /t/'s.

Comment: Yes, but glottal stops only replace /t/s in syllable codas. They don't appear in onsets.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: Then [ˈbʌʔ(superscript n).n̩] :)

Comment: (I'm too lazy to edit my answer.)

Comment: Don’t you think those ᴀʟʟ end in syllabic consonants, whether [n̩], [ɫ̩], or [ɹ̩]? Surely if there’s no vowel after the tap or stop in [ˈlɪdɫ̩], [ˈʍɪdɫ̩], [ˈwɪdɫ̩], [ˈbædɫ̩], [ˈbidɫ̩], [ˈkʰædɫ̩], [ˈkʰɔdɫ̩], [ˈkʰʌdɫ̩], [ˈnidɫ̩], [ˈsʌdɫ̩], [ˈpʰʌdɫ̩], and [ˈpʰudɫ̩], nor in [ˈbiʔn̩], [ˈbɪdn̩], [ˈbɪʔn̩], [ˈhɪdn̩], [ˈlɛdn̩], [ˈsæʔn̩], [ˈseʔn̩], [ˈsʌdn̩], and [ˈwʊdn̩], then there also isn’t one there in [ˈbæɾɹ̩], [ˈbɛɾɹ̩], [ˈbɪɾɹ̩], [ˈbʌɾɹ̩], [ˈflʌɾɹ̩], [ˈfʊɾɹ̩], [ˈluɾɹ̩], [ˈhʊɾɹ̩], [ˈhuɾɹ̩], [ˈkʰʌɾɹ̩], [ˈkʰjuɾɹ̩], [ˈlæɾɹ̩], [ˈmæɾɹ̩], [ˈɻʌɾɹ̩], [ˈɻʊɾɹ̩], [ˈɻuɾɹ̩], [ˈʃʌɾɹ̩], [ˈʃuɾɹ̩], and [ˈwɑɾɹ̩].

Comment: @tchrist: Ah... yes, you're right. But I can't explain it further. Not sure why it happens in *STOP + NASAL/LATERAL* and not in *STOP + APPROXIMANT*. Maybe it sounds weird... who knows.... :)

Comment: I think that some UK accents actually do have a glottal stop in words like *butter* and *bitter*, but I do not myself. Listen to the actor Michael Caine, for example. He does this.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, it's very common in non-rhotic UK accents. Michael Caine speaks non-rhotically. We're talking about rhotic accents here ([....ʔɹ̩]), aren't we?

Comment: Butter -> ['bʌʔə], bitter -> ['bɪʔə] but **not** [bʌʔɹ̩] and [bɪʔɹ̩] (non-rhotic)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul No, it isn't rhoticity. RP has  [ˈbɪtǝ] and  [ˈbʌtǝ] but Cockney has [ˈbɪʔǝ] and  [ˈbʌʔǝ].

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, that's right, but I was talking about syllabic r. My comments were in response to ".......whether [n̩], [ɫ̩], or **[ɹ̩]**...". In simple words, glottal stop rarely (never?) occurs before [ɹ̩]. And I don't know the reason.

Comment: But even non-rhotic speakers *do* have phonemic /r/ at the end of the first word in *better and better*, however you may care to write that phonetically. At least, RP speakers do. I don't know about Cockney.

Comment: @tchrist: You beat me! I don't have an answer to that. :)